# trouble attaching ebs volume to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to attach a ebs volume to an ec2 instance, with this :

```
$response = $ec2->attach_volume($volume_id, $disp['instanceId'], '/dev/sdf');
```

It goes to "attaching" state, then to "attached" state, after few seconds, it goes back to "attaching" state.

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible just a bad EBS controller, but I have not used the SDKs for attaching volumes. May be better to ask this on the Amazon Dev Forums instead, their techs can take a look at it.

Comment: restarting the instance sorted it out, but I wasn't really happy about it..